# Como faço para posicionar duas divs em relação a uma terceira (fixed)?

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Quero que duas divs fiquem abaixo de uma terceira que tem `position: fixed`, o problema é que essas divs ficam atras da terceira, ja tentei mudar a position das duas divs para relative, absolute e static, mas não funciona.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>blogg</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MeuCss.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id = "header">
    <p id = "nome">Titulo/Logo</p>
    <p class = "data">dd/mm/aaaa</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "left"></div>
    <div align="left"></div>
    <div class = "right"></div>
    <div id = "footer"></div>
    <div class = "divLink">
    <a href = "http://www.facebook.com"></a>
    </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div{
    border-radius: 5px;   
}

#header{
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 97.5%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FFCC99;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: fixed;
margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.data{
    float:right;    
margin-right: 5px;
}

.left{
display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
margin-right: 7px;
}

.right{
margin-left: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #00CC99;
float: left;
}

#footer{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #0066FF;
    width: 98.5%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}

#nome{
    margin-left: 5px;   
    color:#009999;
    float: left;
display: inline-block;
}

#email{
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    color:#009999;
}   

.divLink{
    position: static;   
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;    
}

.divLink a{
    display: block;
    background-image: url("http://goo.gl/xPi76J");
    background-size: 50px 50px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius:5px;
}



.divLink a:hover{
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url("http://goo.gl/9t07bt");
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, faça assim:

- Adicione uma div em volta de tudo, pode chamar ela de `.wrap`
- Nessa div, adiciona um margin-top ou padding-top do mesmo tamanho da div que está com position fixed.

Dessa forma, o conteúdo da página, começará sempre abaixo do `.header` ;)

Comment: Valeu, consegui resolver dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Pode dar margin-top nas div que quer que fique pra baixo.

Exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/uU5Bn/

Comment: Não teria como eu colocar margin-top em relação à div header?
Dessa maneira realmente funciona, mas eu queria que as divs se posicionassem de maneira "correta"

Comment: Você esta usando position: fixed, não sei se existe outra forma de fazer isso.